# Import CSV to MySQL with long text fields containing line breaks

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file (';' separated) to a MySQL table.
Normaly, I use a SQL like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local-path/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE tmp_table
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

It always works fine to me, but now I have a CSV with a text field including many '\n','\r', and stuff like that. When I make the import, apparently, MySQL interprets the line breaks as a new field, spoiling all import.

I'd like to know if exists some method to indicate to MySQL to ignore any other symbol except the ';'.

I'm using MySQL workbench to make the import. My CSV have 3 fields (locale,id,terms) and my table have columns locale - VARCHAR(5), id- VARCHAR(50) and terms - TEXT (**here is the problem**).

Here I found some [similar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24203/mysql-import-csv-with-multiple-field-separators) [problems](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51243/import-csv-file-into-mysql-with-multiple-delimiters-field-separators), but apparently is not the same thing, I'm not looking for multiple delimiters, I just want for a way to ignore \n and \r from text fields when I'm importing the CSV.

Comment: How is `LOAD` supposed to know when each "line" is finished?

Comment: @RickJames. Please, correct me if I wrong, but I think that with a three-column table and a CSV separated by ';', the `LOAD` must take a new line every three fields, right? Actually, I don't know how `LOAD` works, but I imagine it to be so.

Comment: Try `LINES TERMINATED BY ''` or `LINES TERMINATED BY ';'`; I suspect that leaving out the clause defaults it to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.  Suggest you experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), you can set both the field and line delimiters in the `LOAD DATA` statement:

```
[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
[LINES
    [STARTING BY 'string']
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
]
```

That should enable you to import the `TEXT` data.  Just be careful in choosing your delimiters!

Comment: I solved the problem some years ago, but your answer is right and it will help someone.

Comment: This answer would be so awesome if it included a working example because so far it's just a quote of the documentation and as far as I am concerned, the StackExchange community mostly saves hours of time of reading the docs